# Oracle: does increasing column size affect the index in any way

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a table which is being used in production for years and has tons of data in it. If i increase the columns size of an indexed column, will I have to rebuild the indexes?

Comment: If you have multi-column indexes and set the column sizes very large you may run into `ORA-01404: ALTER COLUMN will make an index too large`.  On my 11gR2 system, the total size can't be more than 6388 bytes.

Comment: @jonearles that would make a good answer -- no index rebuild required but there's a logical limit on total key length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a VARCHAR2 column, increasing the maximum length does not affect existing data, ergo will not affect your index either.

Comment: Yes this is a varchar type column. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An index contains columns with data and rowid for each row of the table.
So if you increase the length of indexed column, the existing indexes will not be impacted.